# iOS Flutter not getting push notifications

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification

I'm having issues setting up push notifications for iOS on Flutter. 
Another dev tried adding too - had the same problem.

TL;DR: Can anyone get pushes running on iOS Flutter with clean new build from stable channel?

I followed setup steps described here:
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Specifically:

- Generated app ID and push Key in  https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/
- Added info.plist to ios/Runner folder
- Turned on Push capabilities
- Uploaded APNS certificate to Firebase console
- Made sure bundle ID is the same in App / Runner, info.plist and GoogleService-Info.plist
- Added lines in AppDelegate.swift

  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
  }

Pushes aren't coming. Neither when app in background, not at all.

I also tried another step - sending individual push. Send code in CURL looks like this:

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "Authorization:key=AIza_legacy_key" \
   -d \
'{

  "to": "my_push_token",

  "notification": 
  {"body": "test_body",
   "title": "test_title"
  }, 

  "priority": "high", 

}
' \
 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'
```

And the response is always this type:
- First request is InvalidRegistration
- Second and next same calls is NotRegistered

Another person found similar problem this summer and posted on GitHub, but thread was closed:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30486

My Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale ru-UA)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.7 at /Users/reiven/flutter
    • Framework revision 9f5ff2306b (2 weeks ago), 2020-01-26 22:38:26 -0800
    • Engine revision a67792536c
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/reiven/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio 3.6 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.5

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 3.6 Preview.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • iPhone            • 96c120610d684dbab7f5e4d036a7f48041755f96 • ios            • iOS 12.3.1
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • 8ABC99D3-6C46-4A3D-968B-F5719AA92C97     • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)
    • Chrome            • chrome                                   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 79.0.3945.130
    • Web Server        • web-server                               • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
```

p.s. Some things I've tried:

- Used another developer account (100% confirmed pushes are working on another project)
- Used another Firebase account
- Recreated certificates, projects
- Gave to try another developer to setup pushes his own (he also confirmed to be successfull in the past).

Comment: I have the same problem... An ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magically things just started working yesterday evening. 
So first - just try now. If not working - recreate certificates and redo initialization steps. If still not working - pray and retry another day.

Comment: Did you use AppKey or certificates? I have exactly the same problem, my Android app receive push from Firebase but iOS no.

Comment: I have used AppKey.
I know about Android - it always works fine. Problem was with iOS

Comment: the similar issue you faced? https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1690.  removing if #available(iOS 10.0, *)  helped many developers I guess ! doing this will stop getting system tray messages ? only onmessage will be called ?

Comment: @LOG_TAG, I have removed this line but nothing changes... Still, I don't receive pushes.

Comment: @DanielKuta system tray or onMessage:  print("onMessage: $message"); which one you failed to get?

Comment: @LOG_TAG, when I send push from postman I got response "error": "NotRegistered" from Firebase. Methods from Flutter aren't call.